# не работает цикл for c двумя условиями и переменными

Tags: javascript

Мне надо циклом заполнить квадратами поле 20x20 *(1 квадратик это 5% от ширины и длины)*, ведь если вручную, то код будет выглядеть плохо, да и оптимизации будет хуже наверное. Попытался использовать цикл for, но браузер конкретно игнорирует его.

```js
    function s(id) {                    //это чтобы было удобнее
  return document.querySelector(id);
}

function crtf(x, y) {               //эта функция создаёт квадраты, максимальная координата = (19, 19), минимальная = (0, 0), она рабочая
  var ce = document.createElement('div');
  ce.style.position = "absolute";
  ce.style.left = `${+x * 5}%`;
  ce.style.width = "5%";
  ce.style.top = `${+y * 5}%`;
  ce.style.height = "5%";
  ce.style.border = "1px solid black";
  s("#zone").append(ce);
}


const screenWidth = window.screen.width;
const screenHeight = window.screen.height;
window.gz = s("#zone");





for (xt = 0, yt = 0; xt == 20 && yt == 20; xt++) {   //а вот этот злополучный цикл
  if (+xt < 21) {
    crtf(xt, yt);
  }
  else {
    var xt = 0;
    var yt = +yt + 1;
    crtf(xt, yt);
  }
}
```

```css
#zone {
  position:fixed;
  border:3px double black;
  border-radius:3px;
  left:10%;
  right:10%;
  top:10%;
  bottom:10%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Native test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="zone"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Вроде бы в цикле всё правильно. Тем, кто сможет решить эту проблему, заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вы внимательно посмотрите for (xt = 0, yt = 0; xt == 20 && yt == 20; xt++). Вначале xt=0, а потом цикл должен выполняться если xt==20 ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одним циклом не обойтись, надо два вложенных.

```js
    function s(id) {                    //это чтобы было удобнее
  return document.querySelector(id);
}

function crtf(x, y) {               //эта функция создаёт квадраты, максимальная координата = (19, 19), минимальная = (0, 0), она рабочая
  var ce = document.createElement('div');
  ce.style.position = "absolute";
  ce.style.left = `${+x * 5}%`;
  ce.style.width = "5%";
  ce.style.top = `${+y * 5}%`;
  ce.style.height = "5%";
  ce.style.border = "1px solid black";
  s("#zone").append(ce);
}


const screenWidth = window.screen.width;
const screenHeight = window.screen.height;
window.gz = s("#zone");



for (let yt = 0;  yt < 20; yt++){
  for (let xt = 0; xt < 20; xt++){   
      crtf(xt, yt);
   }
}
```

```css
#zone {
  position:fixed;
  border:3px double black;
  border-radius:3px;
  left:10%;
  right:10%;
  top:10%;
  bottom:10%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Native test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="zone"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```